# How to insert into pivot table after form submission using attach?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel eloquent and I'm trying to insert the selected user id from my form and the generated ticket id into my pivot table using attach but I don't know how to do this.

store function

```
 public function store(Request $request
 {        
     $ticket = new Ticket;
     $ticket->organisation_name = $request['organisation_name'];
     $ticket->postal_address = $request['postal_address'];
     $ticket->physical_address = $request['physical_address'];
     $ticket->description_brief = $request['description'];
     $ticket->hours_dedicated = $request['hours'];
     $ticket->commencement_date = $request['start_date'];
     $ticket->due_date = $request['due_date'];
     $ticket->client_id = $request['client_id'];
     $ticket->save();

     //trying to use attach here

     return redirect('/home');
 }
```

form

```
 <form action="TicketsController@store" method="POST">
        {{csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Organisation Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="organisation_name" placeholder="Enter Organisation Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Postal address:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postal_address" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Physical address:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="physical_address" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Client:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="client_id">
                @foreach ($forms as $form)
                <option>{{$form->client->client_id}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Description:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Hours:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hours" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Start date:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="start_date" type="date" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Due date:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="due_date" type="date" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>User:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="id">
                @foreach ($users as $user)
                <option>{{$user->id}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

    </form>
```

User.php

```
 class User extends Authenticatable
 {
 use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
public function tickets(){
    return$this->belongsToMany(Ticket::class,'ticket_user','ticket_id','id');
}
```

Ticket.php

```
 class Ticket extends Model
 {

public function client(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class,'client_id');
}
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'ticket_user','id','ticket_id');
}

protected $primaryKey = 'ticket_id';
public $timestamps = false;

 }
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the `id` (select element) in your form is going to be the `user_id` you want to add to the pivot table?

Comment: What error are you getting when attempting to do what you are explaining? Also, what controller is that store method in?

Comment: yes i would like to add this to my pivot table.

Comment: its in my TicketsController. My main issue is I don't really know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) you can simply pass the `id` you want to attach. After `$ticket->save();` you can add the following:

```
$ticket->users()->attach($request->input('id'));
```

`attach()` will  also work if you pass an array of ids, a model, a collection of ids or a collection of models.

Comment: This seems like it would work for users, but im still unsure how to attach the newly created ticket id from the insert.

Comment: @Mr.t You've lost me. Are you not wanting to add it to the `ticket_user` table? If not, which pivot table are you wanting to add to?

Comment: sorry misunderstood your right. i have tried it but am getting a foreign key constraint error.

Comment: @Mr.t I think have your keys in your relationships the wrong way round. In your Ticket model swap `'id','ticket_id'` to `'ticket_id', 'id'` and the reverse for your `User` model

Comment: thank you so much that was it. It was starting to drive me crazy

Comment: @Mr.t Glad I could help! Going forward I would definitely recommend using Laravel's default convention for column names e.g. in your pivot table have `user_id` instead of just `id`. In this case it would have meant that you don't need to tell Laravel what table and what columns to use, just the model to use i.e. `$this->belongsToMany(Ticket::class);`